# How to get script value using simple html dom?

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get this content:

```
var block = new Block('page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_8', 'block_competition_tables', {"season_id":11663,"round_id":31554,"outgroup":false});
```

on this page:

view-source:http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/regular-season/r31554/?ICID=TN_02_01_02

Actually I made this code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://it.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20152016/regular-season/r31554/?ICID=TN_02_01_02');

foreach ($html->find('script',0) as $element) 
{
   print_r($element);
}
```

But when I'll do the print there isn't no `season_id` and `round_id`, I want to get the value of this element. How I can achieve this?

Comment: What are you getting when you do a print_r? It seems like you are trying to print out a js function as a php array

Comment: I get this: http://pastebin.com/3PciUfge